# Export DataGridVeiw to excel in C# with cell background colors

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have made a [Shift Roster](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz2gm56gduea49q/Shift%20Roster.PNG?dl=0) in DataGridView in winform C#. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1gdytklnsyrub4/Excel-Sheet.PNG?dl=0) is the excel sheet screenshot which I have exported from DataGridView.

I need to export DataGridView as it is to Excel Sheet maintaining the font color and background color also I want not to export first column of DataGridView to excel which is invisible.

I have used the following code to export DataGridView to Excel.

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    // Add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    // Load data from DataTable to the worksheet
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(((DataTable)gvShift.DataSource), true);
    ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

    // Add some styling
    using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, gvShift.Columns.Count])
    {
        rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));
        rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
    }
```

Kindly Help Please....

Comment: What library or dll you are using for excel exporting?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: @MianSalmanNasir Do take a look at EPPlus too.

Comment: That is EPPlus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cells.interior.color

```
Range range = 
            oSheet.get_Range("A" + redRows.ToString(), "J"
                                    + redRows.ToString());

    range.Cells.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: I need to the to export DataGridView cell colors to excel along with data.

Comment: get your required gridview row and read backcolor property  like range.Cells.Interior.Color =  Gridview1.Row[rowindex].Cells[cellindex].BackColor

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I just went though the source from where I was setting the color, put each cell or DataGridView in loop and through range, applied the colors.

Thanks To All For Your Help